# firebase storage - using android camera to upload photo but crashes when submitting the photo to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, camera, firebase-storage

```
public class BidInPutActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

Button submit;
EditText title;
Spinner catg;
EditText dscrp;
EditText qnt;
RadioGroup rptrq_rdo;
RadioButton yes_rdo;
RadioButton no_rdo;
EditText exprdt;
ImageButton upldbtn;
ImageView prdctimg;
StorageReference filepath;
Uri uri;
String bidPhotoUrl;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static  final int REQUEST_READ_PERMISSION = 2;

DatabaseReference databaseBid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bid_in_put_activity);

    filepath = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    databaseBid = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Bids");
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
    title = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.title);
    catg = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.catg);
    dscrp= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dscrp);
    qnt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.qnt);
    rptrq_rdo= (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rptrq_rdo);
    yes_rdo=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.yes_rdo);
    no_rdo=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.no_rdo);
    exprdt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.exprdt);
    upldbtn=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.upldbtn);
    prdctimg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prdctimg);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addBid();
        }
    });
//accessing camera intent and upload to firebase process

    upldbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
           startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
    private void addBid(){
    final String bidtitle=title.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bidcategory=catg.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
    final String biddescription=dscrp.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bidquantity=qnt.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bidrepetitive_requests_yes=yes_rdo.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bidrepetitive_requests_no=yes_rdo.getText().toString().trim();
    final String bidexpiry_date=exprdt.getText().toString().trim();
    if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidtitle))&&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidcategory))
            &&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(biddescription)) &&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidquantity))
            &&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidrepetitive_requests_yes))||(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidrepetitive_requests_no))
            &&(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidexpiry_date))||(!TextUtils.isEmpty(bidPhotoUrl))){

   final StorageReference onlinestorafephotoref = filepath.child("Photo").child(bidtitle).child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

        onlinestorafephotoref.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new 
        OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

               bidPhotoUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
               String id = databaseBid.push().getKey();
               classBidAttributes bid = new classBidAttributes(id,bidtitle,bidcategory,biddescription,bidquantity,
                        bidrepetitive_requests_no,bidrepetitive_requests_yes,bidexpiry_date,bidPhotoUrl);

                databaseBid.child(id).setValue(bid);
                Toast.makeText(BidInPutActivity.this, "Bid added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                Toast.makeText(BidInPutActivity.this, "Submit Failure ! Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bidPhotoUrl = "";
                String id = databaseBid.push().getKey();
                classBidAttributes bid = new classBidAttributes(id,bidtitle,bidcategory,biddescription,bidquantity,
                        bidrepetitive_requests_no,bidrepetitive_requests_yes,bidexpiry_date,bidPhotoUrl);
                databaseBid.child(id).setValue(bid);
            }
        }); finish();*/

        Toast.makeText(BidInPutActivity.this, "Bid added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(BidInPutActivity.this, "Fill in missing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        uri = data.getData();
        Glide.with(BidInPutActivity.this).load(uri).into(prdctimg);
    }
}
}
```

PS: the code works fine if i removed all the photo upload related parts of code, as it well upload the text inputs to `firebase realtime database`, i've made sure that my `manifest` includes the camera permission and the **read_external_storage permission**, and i've made sure that accessing camera is permitted in case of **marshmallow**, so hopefully somebody well help because this is driving me nuts, tell me if u need any additional info.

```
    ///////// CrashLog//////////

09-06 10:36:12.293 3616-3616/com.mrmazen.cbid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.mrmazen.cbid, PID: 3616
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
                                                                at com.mrmazen.cbid.BidInPutActivity.addBid(BidInPutActivity.java:122)
                                                                at com.mrmazen.cbid.BidInPutActivity.access$000(BidInPutActivity.java:30)
                                                                at com.mrmazen.cbid.BidInPutActivity$1.onClick(BidInPutActivity.java:75)
                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Please paste crash log

Comment: i've just added the crashlog

Comment: ok i've been able to figure out where is the source of the problem, its the uri "uri.getLastPathSegment()", i've made a condition that if the uri is null to display a toast instead of continuing the process and it worked telling me that the uri is null, so now the app doesn't crash but the uri is not working, i'm still unable to figure out how to make it work though

Comment: it surely has something todo with the onActivityResult method, as the uri = data.getData(); is not really invoking any data.

Answer (score 0):

Please note getting a `Uri` back from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not documented, and camera apps do not need to return a Uri.Supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT` in your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` Intent, in which case you know where the image should be stored.

```
final Intent pictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            Uri pictureUri=getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
            //pass your uri as an Extra here
            pictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,pictureUri);
            startActivityForResult(pictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

In `onActivityResult` check if `null`.once you have `Uri` feed it to `Glide`

```
        //get path here
          picturePath= pictureUri.getPath();
```